# SQL server where clause (compare more values in more values)

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE ('Paris','London', 'Dublin', 'Venice')  in (SELECT city FROM Europe)
```

`SELECT city FROM Europe` return more than one value,

how can I do this?

i dont want to repeat the condition like:

```
WHERE ('Paris')  in (SELECT city FROM Customers) 
      or ('London')  in (SELECT city FROM Customers) 
      or  ('Dublin')  in (SELECT city FROM Customers) or ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second select is redundant, and you can just "flip" `in` condition.

So equivalent of your query is:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE city in ('Paris','London', 'Dublin', 'Venice')
```

**Update.**

Based on logic you've disclosed in comments, you query should be something like:

```
select * from Customers
where exists(select top 1 * from Europe where city in ('Paris','London', 'Dublin', 'Venice'))
```

Exactly as was stated: if exists at least one of city in ('Paris','London', 'Dublin', 'Venice') in `Europe` then everything from `Customers` will be selected, else nothing will be selected.

Comment: My bad, the "inside" select was not in same table, I've edited

Comment: @MattewTrincanati in this case I don't understand the meaning of this `where` condition. It doesn't use any column from `Customers` table, so basically it is like "if some set is it `Europe` table, then select all from Customers, else select nothing". Is there any reason for such a query? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: The where clause is going to work like an if else statement, like: "if selecting this I have in the result one of those ('Paris','London', 'Dublin', 'Venice'), then select all the values, else do nothing".
I cannot add a real if statement cause is all inside a locked query inside a cms, I can only modify the where.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `in` and the column name. `IN` is equivalent to `or`, which is `city = 'Paris' or city = 'London'`.. in your case.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE city in ('Paris','London', 'Dublin', 'Venice')
```

Edit: Using `exists`

```
SELECT c.* FROM Customers c
WHERE exists (select 1 from Europe where city = c.city
              and city in ('Paris','London', 'Dublin', 'Venice')
```

Comment: My bad, the "inside" select was not in same table, I've edited

Comment: customers has not a city column inside, so c.city is invalid